# Поддомены домена

Tags: dns

Существуют ли какие-то ограничения на количество поддоменов и количество уровней у домена ?

А так же, если обладаете информацией.

- Какое количество символов может быть у доменов 0-го, 1-го уровня и т.д. ?

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения, гуглил, найти не мог, а как задал тут вопрос, сразу нашёл.

> Максимальное количество уровней поддоменов — 127, и каждый из них
>   может содержать 63 символа, пока общая длина доменного имени не
>   достигнет длины в 255 символов. Некоторые регистраторы доменных имён
>   устанавливают более жёсткие требования.

Comment: [The DNS itself places only one restriction on the particular labels
   that can be used to identify resource records.  That one restriction
   relates to the length of the label and the full name.  The length of
   any one label is limited to between 1 and 63 octets.  A full domain
   name is limited to 255 octets (including the separators).](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2181#section-11). ни о каких «127 уровнях» речи нет.

Comment: Ну их видимо больше 127 быть не может xD. По символу на уровень 255/2 = 127